# Angular full calendar + bootstrap 4 - how should I use them together?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I am developing a meal planner using Angular + Bootstrap 4 + full calendar.
The layout is like this:
[calendar layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxi3H.png)

My application uses Bootstrap, I want to fit my calendar into container > row > col-7

Can you please guide me on how to include full calendar into angular + bootstrap 4?

I tried the below,

1. **WORKS - just angular full calendar - no bootstrap 4, no plugin** :
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fullcalendar-j7fcji?
2. **Doesn't work - Width and height of calendar not set correctly: angular + bootstrap 4 - no plugin** : This is the same code as (1) with just bootstrap layout added.
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-sq9vpt?
3. **Throws an error: angular + bootstrap 4 - with plugin** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-zkkafp?file=src/app/app.component.ts
   I followed the instructions on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme.

**(1)** is exactly what I want - but it breaks when I introduce bootstrap container, row and column.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 border">
        <app-diet-type></app-diet-type>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 border custom-cal-width">
        <h4 class="row justify-content-start py-md-4 pr-md-4 font-weight-bold font-italic">
            Step 2: Select date of delivery
        </h4>
        <app-full-calendar (dayClicked)="onDateSelect($event)"></app-full-calendar> --> THE CALENDAR SHOWS UP BUT ITS HEIGHT AND WIDTH IS NOT CORRECT
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11 border">
        <app-delivery-address></app-delivery-address>
    </div>
</div>
```

Versions: Angular 2, Full calendar : 5.5.0, Bootstrap 4.5.2

NOTE: I am open to using other calendars as well. Please feel free to direct me to any responsive calendar that works with Angular + Bootstrap.

Comment: @isherwood - updated the 'what breaks' part. I am not familiar with Angular bootstrap, but I tried date picker and the calendar it comes with - the calendar width was not set correctly. The calendar must fill the parent, but it was much smaller. Do you recommend using Angular bootstrap? Can you give me an reference to some place where angular bootstrap + calendar (any calendar - not just full calendar) is used?

Comment: I was apparently mistaken about ngBootstrap providing layout. It's been a while. Please don't direct your specific questions to me in comments. Update your post and let the community help. We're not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing `@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';` in `style.css`. Add it and it will work like charm.

[image]

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-fnv8nh-ns

Comment: Thankyou @Nimitt Shah for your answer. I have a question - As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#css-importing, we no longer need to incluse the main.css. Am I understanding the document wrong?

Comment: I just realised I was using ver 4.4.2 in the stackblitz code :     "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.2", "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.4.2", "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.4.2" - Sorry for the confusion